Images being squished only on android
According to shop customers, product thumbnail images of this website are being distorted on android devices (apparently on Chrome). I can't see anything special about CSS of this elements nor i don't have any access to android device to check it. On all the devices I'm using and have access to (none of them being Android), thumbnails are displayed properly. This is how they look according to customer reports:

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing thumbnail list images on this website to be distorted on android devices? Thank you.

Sounds to me like you lack the resources to reproduce the so-called issue. My suggestion is using the browser's console inspector tool to select a responsive android-made mobile screen (e.g Pixel 7) from the predefined list. Debug using your browser's tool and then refine your question with your findings before blaming a browser and/or OS.

It would happen on other devices based on the resolution.
The problem is that not all the images you use in the srcset are square in dimensions. But you have a css class on the images that does aspect-ration: 1/1 so, square.
So, when an image is selected from the list you have that is not square it will be distorted to become square.
As a workaround, you could add object-fit: contain on those img tags so that it will retain the image dimensions.

Keep in mind that some of the images defined in srcset are also cropped.

Oh wow, i have not realized that different size variants are not cropped to square. Thank you for that reply and extended explanaiton!
